# Core Data Fetch requests slow on large data set

Tags: ios, core-data, subquery, large-files, nsfetchrequest

This is my first Core Data project, and I need advice on speeding up my fetch requests.

My Core Data model contains 2 entities, `Wells` and `Fluids`.  `Wells` has 50,000 records, and `Fluids` has 2 million records. They look like the following.

```
Wells
nams  
relation  
wellsToFluids

Fluids
text1, text2, etc.  
relation  
fluidsToWells
```

Fetch requests on `Wells` are very fast. Fetch requests on `Wells` combined with data from `Fluids` accessed via compound predicates via the `wellsToFluids` relation are slow.  And, I am seeing unexpected fetch times on different predicates.

I am building a compound predicate, based on user selections. But basically the situation is the following

Searches on `Wells`:

```
predicateWithFormat: @"(wellNumber == 1)"
```

*.001 sec*

Searches on Fluids:

```
predicateWithFormat: @"(ANY  wellsToFluids.text2 CONTAINS[c] stringToFind)"
```

*1.3 sec. (on Mac simulator – REALLY slow on iPhone or iPad)*

Fetch on `Wells` and `Fluids`:

```
predicateWithFormat: @"(wellNumber == 1)  AND (ANY  wellsToFluids.text1 CONTAINS[c] stringToFind)"
```

*3.2 sec.*

Fetch on `Wells` and multiple `Fluids` attributes:

```
predicateWithFormat: @"(wellNumber == 1)  AND (ANY  wellsToFluids.text1 CONTAINS[c] stringToFind) AND (ANY  wellsToFluids.text2 CONTAINS[c] stringToFind)"
```

*6 sec.*

Changing `Fluids` portion of predicate to subquery yeld weird results.

Fetch on only `Fluids` with subquery:

```
predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(wellsToFluids, $x, ANY $x.text1 CONTAINS[c] stringToFind).@count !=0)"
```

*12 sec.*

Fetch on `Wells` and `Fluids` with subquery:

```
predicateWithFormat: @"(wellNumber == 1)  AND  (SUBQUERY(wellsToFluids, $x, ANY $x.text1 CONTAINS[c] stringToFind).@count !=0)"
```

*3.2 sec.*

Time does not change for additional attributes added in fetch from `Fluids`, stays at a fairly constant 3.2 sec.

Also tried fetching from `Fluids`, then using relation back to `Wells` – but that did not improve speed.

Can someone can give me some pointers on improving the fetch setup or it is just a feature of 2 million records?

Comment: Text matching predicates (such as CONTAINS) are generally much slower then a simple "number == 1", in particular if you search with [c] (case insensitive). I would start by checking if "ANY wellsToFluids.text1 CONTAINS stringToFind" or "ANY wellsToFluids.text1 == stringToFind" makes a difference in speed.

Comment: thanks - actually did try that. Like you, figured it would make quite a difference, but it did not make a significant difference.

Comment: This is a good question but next time, please, format it in the correct manner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here some hints to achieve what you want. Anyway, you always need to measure your changes to see if they are valid or not. It's a feedback process. Change and measure. Change and measure and so on.

- Prefetched relationships
- Use batches
- Prefer `beginwith` or `endswith` instead of `contains`
- Avoid [cd] when necessary
- Normalize strings
- ...

These are just hints.

**I really suggest to take a look [High Performance Core Data](http://highperformancecoredata.com/) blog**. There are a video, slides and code on how to achieve this. **Matthew Morey** did a very good job.

Also Apple Developer site (you must be a member to watch it), in **WWDC 2013 Videos**, has a session called **Core Data Performance Optimization and Debugging (session 211)** which talks about performance.

Comment: Thanks for feedback.  Sorry for formatting - new to site. Will do better next time!!  Blog you suggested is great.