# Large data insert in Core Data and relationships

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Apple's documentation states that for an efficient insert of bulk data in core data based iOS 7 application, one must first perform a straight insert leaving aside the relationships in first phase. Then in second phase performing an update then the relationships comes into scene.

My question is: for a bulk insert of say 400000 records in a table having relationships with other tables, isn't it an expensive operation that the application first runs a loop 400000 to perform a straight insert then another loop of 400000 to establish the relationship between tables?

Is there any efficient way to do this or one need to follow above sequence only?

Answer (score 0):

My suggest is to perform import operations in batches. So, for example, import the first N data, save and reset and so on. This mechanism allows you to manage the memory footprint and if, you want, enables the user to work with initial data, i.e. while you are importing remaining batches the user can interact with initial ones.

To calculate N you should rely on Core Data Instrument since it the only way to get objective times for your import operations. There is no other way I guess.

In my other SO reply you could find some good references that describe the best approaches to import data: [Core Data Fetch requests slow on large data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461970/core-data-fetch-requests-slow-on-large-data-set/20472578#20472578).

Comment: batching is a good way to balance disk I/O, however it doesn't have any advantages regarding relationship validation performance.

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits I agree with you. Anyway, based on my experience, the only thing to do is to measure the importing phase to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

It is expensive to run a 400k record insert twice. However relationship validation is expensive and thats why the documentation recommends leaving them out of the initial insert.

You can also calculate the relationships that need to be hooked up during the initial insert, thereby constraining the duration of the second pass.